# The command was found in the module, but the module could not be loaded

Tags: linux, powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create document in cosmosdb using PowerShell. The command is being run on PSCore on Linux, the execution policy is `Unrestricted` and unchangeable.

I am running into this error:

> New-CosmosDbDocument : The 'New-CosmosDbDocument' command was found in
>   the module 'CosmosDB', but the module could not be loaded. For more
>   information, run 'Import-Module CosmosDB'

Here is the code:

```
Import-Module CosmosDB

$Guid = $([Guid]::NewGuid().ToString())
$document = @" { ... } "@

$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $CosmosDbAccountName
-Database $DatabaseName -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroupName     New-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $CollectionId -DocumentBody $document -PartitionKey "$Guid"
```

Comment: Hi, have you install-module -Name CosmosDB ? Please try only the import-module -Name CosmosDB

Comment: At this GitHub https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB they import with "import-module -Name CosmosDB"

Comment: So what happens if you follow the instruction in the error? `For more information, run 'Import-Module CosmosDB'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please check if the CosmosDB module is installed in Powershell Core?
if not, please install it using the below command.

**Install-Module -Name CosmosDB**

If you already have it installed, please run the below command to check if the cmdlet is available

**get-help New-CosmosDbDocument**

If you do not have the above cmdlet, please update your Powershell core module

**update-module CosmosDb**

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had multiple versions of several AWS.tools.* modules so I uninstalled them via Uninstall-Module then reinstalled them via Install-Module and this resolved the errors I was seeing.